# BASH Hackerrank Solution works on PC, but not on Hackerrank

Tags: bash, runtime-error

Trying to solve this Hackerrank problem " [Equalize the Array](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equality-in-a-array/problem) " using BASH.  Here's my Solution:

```
read size
mostfreq=$(tr "[:space:]" '\n' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -r -k1 | head -c7 | tr -d "[:space:]")
expr $size - $mostfreq
```

Passes all test cases except

```
22
51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51
```

When I run on PC, it produces the expected output 0. (0 = minimum deletions to produce an array of only duplicates). However, when I run using Hackerrank platform it gives me a runtime error. I was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem when using BASH on the Hackerrank platform.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, on Hackerrank, you will be getting an error if your expression evaluates to `0`. So, any test containing an array which elements are all equal will fail, even the simplest one consisting of a single element:

```
1
```

The way I overcame this issue was to evaluate the expression using '' and then printing the result using `echo` as below:

```
result=`expr $size - $mostfreq`
echo $result
```

Hence, the full code may look as follows:

```
read size
mostfreq=$(tr "[:space:]" '\n' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -r -k1 | head -c7 | tr -d "[:space:]")
result=`expr $size - $mostfreq`
echo $result
```